# WCF service fails on Windows Server 2003/IIS6 - The underlying connection was closed

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I'm experiencing an issue with a WCF service. It is running WebHTTP binding and is a service that receives images.

The problem is that with some images the server fails to receive the incoming stream. The problem is not about size. It can receive files at 100Kb and 4 MB, but fail at files at 800kb. A "defect" image will never succeed, and "good" images will always succeed.

My current suspect is the IIS 6. We have it running in both test and production in house on IIS 7 and IIS 7.5, but at this customer site with IIS 6 it fails.

I can't figure out how to get more debugging info out of IIS 6 to come closer to why it is cutting of the connection.

Below is the nasty details, as I see relevant.

I hope somebody has been here before, and are able to assist me forward.

**The Machine**

Windows 2003 R2, SP2 + IIS 6, + .Net 2.0 + 3.5

**WCF**

I have changed the Transfermode to Buffered for my WCF service, and after I did that, the service code don't even get invoked. So I don't suspect WCF settings.

I have enabled meesageLogging for WCF, which again give me almost nothing.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="-1"/>
    </diagnostics>
```

Logging at the log file afterwards gives me the following:

Basic Information:

> Activity Name: Processing message 1.
>
> Time: 2012-03-22 09:27:56.1996
>
> Level: Error
>
> Source: System.ServiceModel
>
> Process: w3wp
>
> Thread: 12

Exception Message:

> The number of bytes available is inconsistent with the HTTP Content-Length header.  There  may have been a network error or the client may be sending invalid requests.

Exception Stakctrace:

> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ReadBufferedMessage(Stream
>   inputStream)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpInput.ParseIncomingMessage(Exception&
>   requestException)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestContext.CreateMessage()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.HttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext
>   context, ItemDequeuedCallback callback)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult
>   result)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object
>   state)
>   System.ServiceModel.PartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object
>   state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke2()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.WorkItem.Invoke()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ProcessCallbacks()
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.CompletionCallback(Object
>   state)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOThreadScheduler.CriticalHelper.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.Utility.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32
>   error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
>   System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32
>   errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

Again, evidence that it is not our WCF service that is responsible for the error, but somewhere in the WCF pipeline.

**HTTPERR**

I have checked the HTTPERR logs of the IIS, and nothing there but Timer_ConnectionIdle entries, which should be irrelevant.

**Fiddler**

Fiddler just states the obvious:

[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.

If there is any need for more information let me know, and I will submit it.

Best regards
/Anders

Answer (score 1):

So I was having this issue too. At first I thought it might be a threading issue (though it was against my better judgement).  I made my service calls thread safe and then got down to the real exception after I got past the worker process crashing.  The issue for me turned out to be that I was writing to and reading from a share with a given credential using impersonation.  However, the share wasn't able to get anymore connections.  Even though I was logging out (closing the handle) apparently the connections were still hanging around.  What I ended up doing was using a  MemoryCache to keep tokens around a little longer and reuse them when the share and user were the same for any given piece of media in my database.

I'm not sure if yours is the same issue but we were def having the same symptoms.  My WCF service is reading and writing to a share.  Using a SafeThread class (I modified code from here original source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SafeThread.aspx) I was able to keep the worker process from crashing and see my real error get logged.

Knowledge base article.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/179483

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Note: We were also seeing this behavior when the WCF service was hosted on a Server 2008/IIS7 box.

Comment: Hi, I don't believe this is what's causing our bug. We experience the error before trying to write the file to a network share. As we stream the image to the server, it fails on some files, and only uploading a part of them. As mentioned, when buffered transportmode is enabled, the WCF service don't even get called. We suspect some network elements, but haven't got response from the customer yet. But they claim to have solved the issue, we just don't know how yet.